# personify VS embody

Tags: word-choice, difference

Embody means to represent (a quality) in bodily or material form

Personify means to be the perfect example of a person who has (a quality)

My tutor said she felt they can be used interchangeably in the following six sentences.

1. These children personify/embody all that is wrong with the education system.
2. Carter personifies/embodies the values of self-reliance and hard work.
3. He is a leader who embodies/personifies courage.
4. She embodies/personifies the principles.
5. That politician embodies/personifies the hopes of black youth.
6. As John Adams embodies/personifies the old style, Andrew Jackson embodies/personifies the new.

But she said it’s her personal bias that it’s weird to use “personify” in the 7th sentence, but couldn’t explain why.

**7. She embodies/personifies everything I admire in a teacher.**

Is this true and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that this is wrong. I think that your tutor says this because it is strange to personify something that is already a person, like a teacher. Even though you are technically saying that she personifies **everything I admire** in a teacher, the verb "to personify" specifically implies making something that is not human, like a certain quality or idea, into human form.

That being said, I see nothing wrong with the way you used `personify` in sentence 7. `Everything I admire in a teacher` is abstract enough that you can use either personify or embody. However, as an example, it would be **wrong** to say, `she personifies a good teacher`. It would be **correct** to say, `she embodies a good teacher`.

In short, `to personify` is for someone to represent something abstract and nonhuman, while `to embody` is for someone to represent anything at all. They greatly overlap in definition, but they are not quite the same.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I thought to embody is for someone to represent Things, so it's better to say "she embodies the valuable traits of a good teacher" than "she embodies a good teacher", unless "a good teacher" is used metephorically.